# `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` when a decorator function is called

Tags: python, python-decorators

I get a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` error when a decorator function is caleld. E.g. I
call the function `msgReturnAsList`, which is actually meant to return a list and therefore I do not understand why is it throwing an error that a `str object is not callable`.

I read at [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-how-to-fix-in-python/) that this TypeError occurs mainly in two occasions, neither of which has anything to do with my case:
1."If You Use str as a Variable Name in Python"
2. "If You Call a String Like a Function in Python"

Can somebody clarify what is the logic behind this and how do I get `msgReturnAsList` to return the string converted to upper by `wrapThis` and then converted to a list by the problematic decorator function `msgReturnAsList`?

```
def wrapThis(a):
    a = str(a).upper()
    return a 

@wrapThis
def msgReturnAsList(msg):
    msg = list(msg)
    return msg

b = "Convert to upper and output it as a list of letters."
print(msgReturnAsList(b))
```

I tired changing the list to string, interestingly the error remains the same.

Comment: The return value of a decorator *replaces* the object being decorated.  Yours returns a string, so `msgReturnAsList` is now a name that refers to a string, rather than a function.  "If You Call a String Like a Function in Python" is *exactly* what you're doing here.

Answer (score 1):

A decorator method should return a method:

```
def wrapThis(func):
    def wrapper_func(msg):
        msg = str(msg).upper()
        return func(msg)
    return wrapper_func

@wrapThis
def msgReturnAsList(msg):
    msg = list(msg)
    return msg

b = "Convert to upper and output it as a list of letters."
print(msgReturnAsList(b))
```

[How to Create and Use Decorators in Python With Examples](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-decorators-explained-with-examples/)

Comment: This is completely ignoring `msgReturnAsList` and just executing the decorator. If you want to actually utilize the decorated function you need to do something like `return func(str(a).upper())` in `wrapper_func` in your decorator.

Comment: Why would you say it "is ignoring msgReturnAsList" as it actually returns a list: ['C', 'O', 'N', 'V', 'E', 'R', 'T', ' ', 'T', 'O', ' ', 'U', 'P', 'P', 'E', 'R', ' ', 'A', 'N', 'D', ' ', 'O', 'U', 'T', 'P', ...].. etc.? [url](https://onlinegdb.com/NLivX9T9e)
 I am not sure, what do you mean exactly, can you give more details?